# "expiration date" for non-edible items

Tags: phrase-request, translation

I have a table listing microbiology equipment supplies like microtubes, microplates etc. The rightmost column is called "срок годности" in Russian, which means "term of suitability", and is usually translated as "expiration date". The data in the column are in the format "12.2017" (month.year).

But isn't "expiration date" for edible and/or organic items and other "[expiring](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/40297/expiry-date-or-expiration-date-label)" things only? The microtubes won't "expire", they might last several centuries yet, due to being made of plastic.

What could be a better name for this particular column? "Use by date"?

Comment: RE: _But isn't "expiration date" for edible items and other "expiring" things only?_ Well, expiration dates can be found on [coupons](http://www.mrsjanuary.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Coupon-Expiration-Date.jpg), too, for example.

Comment: @J.R. - that fits into the "expiring things" category, IMHO. The expiration date there is for the discount offer.

Comment: And meat, milk, and bread don't themselves "expire"; they're usually already dead when you get them.

Comment: @StoneyB - so it's okay to use "expiration date" for pieces of equipment, accessories, supplies etc?

Comment: `Expiration Date` and `Use By Date` are synonymous.

Comment: It doesn't bother me. *Something* expires, whether it's usability or amortization or efficiency.

Comment: @gattsbr - but on the credit card, the date denotes the expiration of service provided by the bank. A pipette does not merely denote that some service is being provided. The expiration date concerns the intrinsic quality of the pipette.

Comment: @StoneyB - I see. If it's idiomatic, I'll use it then.

Comment: How about "end of life", like this kind of usage: [*end of life*](http://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life)? See [*End-of-life (product)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-life_(product))

Comment: Generally stuff like that would have a warranty on it rather than an expiration date. [Product Warranty: Defects In Materials and Workmanship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warranty#Defects_In_Materials_and_Workmanship)

Comment: @gattsbr Warranty only refers to manufacturer responsibility for any defects. Has nothing to do with product support or useful life.

Comment: Is the equipment in sterile packaging which may begin to break down after a while? http://www.dupont.com/products-and-services/packaging-materials-solutions/pharmaceutical-packaging/brands/tyvek-sterile-packaging.html

Comment: I think you're completely mistaken if you suppose that most (or even, *many*, today) things made of plastic will last for centuries. As it says [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/287457667_Conservation_of_plastics_Materials_science_degradation_and_preservation): *Plastic objects are included more than ever in museums and galleries collections these days, but these items can start to deteriorate when they a just a few years old.* There are plenty of reasons to design plastics with limited lifespans, or simply not bother trying to increase longevity.

Comment: "maintain sterility for at least five years":  http://www.dupont.com/products-and-services/packaging-materials-solutions/pharmaceutical-packaging/brands/tyvek-sterile-packaging/articles/microbial-barrier-tyvek.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do tend to think of "expiration date" as being for food (at least initially) but it's used quite often to refer to non-edible things.

For example, child safety seats have "expiration dates":

> [Car Seat Expiration](http://www.gracobaby.com/customerservice/pages/safetyinformation.aspx) – Did you know your car seat expires? Graco stamps an expiration date into the bottom of each car seat so you know when it is time to replace it. Expiration dates can range anywhere from six to ten years or more depending on the car seat – so it’s important to check your particular seat.

So, this "expiration date" is the date that they believe the plastic to have degraded enough that it is no longer safe to continue using.

I think that, since it sounds similar to your use, "expiration date" would be an acceptable phrase.